# Can I use an enum with Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have created an enum

```
enum FeedItemType: String {
    case selling = "SELLING"
    case news = "USER_NEWS"
}
```

The string matches a `type` property being returned in my JSON response.

I'd like to be able to use the enum value elsewhere in my code when using the struct I am creating. Is this possible?

I was trying something like this

```
struct FeedItem: Codable, Equatable {
    var type: FeedItemType

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.type = try container.decode(FeedItemType.self, forKey: .type)
    }
}
```

But I am getting numerous erros

> No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type
>   'FeedItemType'
>
> Type 'FeedItem' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Comment: `enum FeedItemType: String, Codable {`

Comment: Also your struct has lot of redundant code. You can get rid of `CodingKeys` enum and `init` with `Decoder`

Comment: `struct FeedItem: Codable, Equatable {
    enum Kind: String, Codable { case selling = "SELLING", news = "USER_NEWS" }
    var kind: Kind
}`

Comment: @RobertDresler true, although I just copied and pasted the relevant code, there is more going on in the response that just that property